nginx change file name
enter image description here
enter image description here
I deployed a React project using Nginx on Amazon Linux, but the CSS isn't being applied. Upon investigation, I noticed that the name of the built CSS file is different when using Nginx compared to when using npx serve -s build in the local environment. As shown in the screenshot, it's normal in the local environment, but abnormal when using Nginx. How can I resolve this error?
I tried reinstalling Nginx, but there was no change.
